# Adding query layer to MXD in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, query-layer, error-000732

I want to add a query layer to an arcmap document so that whenever i have  a db data update, it is reflected in my ma and I can update my service through python script. This is my script so far...

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overWriteOutput = 1

# define local variables
wrkspc = 'C:/ArcGIS_Workspace/'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(wrkspc + 'scripts/Trial.mxd')

input_db_name = "Database Connections/xxx.sde"
outLayer = "DynamicQueryLayer"
out_layer_name = wrkspc +"/shapefiles/DynamicQueryLayer.lyr"
query = "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE"

#unique key for the table
oid_field = "schema.TEST_TABLE.TEST_ID"

try:

    # Create a query layer
    arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management (input_db_name, outLayer, query, oid_field)
    
    # save the created query layer
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(outLayer, out_layer_name, "ABSOLUTE")

    # Get the created layer
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(out_layer_name)

    # get the data frame of the given mxd
    data_frame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

    # Switch to data view
    mxd.activeView = data_frame.name
    
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(data_frame, lyr, 'TOP')
    print "Added layer to the MXD ..."

    mxd.save()
    print "MXD saved..."    
except Exception, e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

I get this error

> ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset DynamicQueryLayer does not exist
> or is not supported.

I am sure there is a way to save the created query layer as a layer file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GP tool [Save To Layer File (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000):

> Creates an output layer file (.lyr) that references geographic data
>   stored on disk.

Alternatively, you could use the [`.save`/`.saveACopy` methods](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) on the Layer object

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to save an intermediate layer file and then load it.

`MakeQueryLayer_management` returns a "result" object:

```
r = arcpy.MakeQueryLayer_management (input_db_name, outLayer, query, oid_field)
print(r)
# <Result 'DynamicQueryLayer'>
```

This result object is indexable, and the first item happens to contain the layer object:

```
print(r[0])
# <map layer u'DynamicQueryLayer'>
print(type(r[0]))
# <class 'arcpy._mapping.Layer'>
# Just to see what else is in there, we can convert to a list:
print(list(r))
# [<map layer u'DynamicQueryLayer'>]
# The layer is the only element.
```

This object can be added to the MXD's data frame directly:

```
lyr = r[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(data_frame, lyr, 'TOP')
mxd.save()
```

<sub>This was done with ArcGIS 10.5.1. I can't guarantee other versions are identical, but I'd be surprised if any of this changes. Then again, lots of things in ESRI are surprising.</sub>